# DynamoDB - SerializationException, Unexpected value type in payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am trying to Query a dynamodb table, using the primary and sort keys. No GSI involved. But getting the below exception. Can you please help me with this?

```
{
  "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException",
  "Message": "Unexpected value type in payload"
}
```

This is the payload to the Query. Here context is the primary key and id is the sort key.

```
{
    "TableName": "vsm.data",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "context = :e AND begins_with(id, :m)",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":e": "event",
        ":m": "sdafsd"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you gave more context it would be helpful, something closer to the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The expression attribute values map expects the data type  along with values. So the request should be

```
{
    "TableName": "vsm.data",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "context = :e AND begins_with(id, :m)",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":e": {"S": "event"},
        ":m": {"S": "sdafsd"}
    }
}
```